# How can I change visibility with jQuery after toggle

Tags: jquery-ui, toggle

I have a jQuery toggle on a div "pastmeet" which I need to set visibility on programmatically (without a click) after the toggle. I set the style for the div to display:block; and added a (show) and then a CSS alter to jQuery. Regardless of what I do, the div doesn't show, and the source code show the div is assigned a display:none. How do I show the div after toggle has turned it off? Here's my existing code:

```
    (function ($) {
       $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".div_toggle").slideUp();
            $(".toggle_action").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".div_toggle").slideToggle("slow");
      });
        $('.pastmeet').css('display', 'block');  // force visibility to on          
      return false;
    });         
  })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to toggle between show and hide, you can just use:

```
  $(".toggle_action").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".div_toggle").toggle();
  });
```

but if you have to do something more custom, this is what i've done in the past:

```
var showHide = 0;
  $(".toggle_action").click(function(){
        if (showHide == 0) {
              showHide = 1;
              $(this).next(".div_toggle").hide();
             //do something
        } else {
              showHide = 0;
              $(this).next(".div_toggle").show();
             //do something
  });
```